# What is the good directory/location to add codes in Android framework

Tags: android, android-source, android-framework

I have two doubts need a hint or favour.

Basically I am trying to add some Library source into framework so can call these apis from Application, and also call JNI files from my library.

I have tried adding my library in  `framework/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/"library folders"` ,because this library is related to bluetooth so i thought adding it here. Now i have read somewhere that new libraries should be added at `base/core/` folder.

Anybody please suggest what is good location to add files(Java and aidl both).

another question is how can i link `jni` and files available in `external/` folder with my library. i am trying from several days but no luck. please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you make an image for your own use and the api you try to add is related to bluetooth, then  `framework/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/` is a good place to put your code.

`framework/base/core/java/` - is a folder where you put your java code
`framework/base/core/java/android/*` - the code from this folder will be added as API (if you not specify @hide tag)
`framework/base/core/java/com/*` - the code will not be added as API.

As for the second question try to look at the post ["Remixing Android"](http://marakana.com/s/post/1044/remixing_android). I hope it will help you. If not you can specify further your question so that SO community will have a chance to help you.

Comment: Great thanks @Yuri, just want to let you know it is not an image, I am trying to add java and aidl files, yeah related to bluetooth.
I will go through the link, let you know soon.